# How to join multiple tables in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join

I have 4 tables  CustomerEntity, CustomerMaster,Request and UserMaster
  and have following structure of the tables,

```
CustomerEntity  (id,address,branch,branch_id,city,entity_status,request_id,user_master_id)
CustomerMaster (id,customer_name,customer_type)  
UserMaster(id,customer_master_id,employee_id,unique_id,employee_id)  
Request(id,customer_master_id,parent_request_id,request_status,user_master_id)
```

when I'm making a query from Hibernate like this

```
sb.append("select c from CustomerEntity c, Request r ")
```

it provides me correct data that I need, but now there is a case where I need to capture the UserMaster id as well as CustomerMaster id value as well, which can only be fetched by joining the UserMaster and CustomerMaster table with the existing query, but I'm not sure where I will get all the projected data as in the above query I'm getting the data on 'c' but in the new query I want all the values from the query executed after joining all these 4 tables.

I'm using the following query:

```
sb.append("select * from  (CustomerEntity as c join Request as r
  on r.id = c.request_id)
  left join  CustomerMaster as c1 on r.customer_master_id = c1.id 
  left join UserMaster as u
  on r.customer_master_id = u.customer_master_id");
```

in the Hibernate like this but it seems not to working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to join an arbitrary number of tables in hibernate (JPA). How the data should be returned depends on the needs of your business requirements.

In your examples it seems you are creating native SQL queries leveraging a StringBuilder / StringBuffer, right? Thats not needed, resp. not helpful in most cases.

Usually hibernate is applied to return mapped Entities, in other words, Java objects representing the data of your database tables. Then you can work with this objects using it's accessors and mutators (getters and setters) within the current persistence context or even in a detached state.

With the hibernate mapping you can define relations allowing you to access all assigned objects by navigating through the graph via Java method calls.

Maybe take a look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-associations-unidirset).

But that presumes that you use the abilities of the ORM layer to access the data, that means either entity queries (access methods) invoked on the Session / EntityManager object, an HQL / JPQL query or using the Criteria API.

[This](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-workingpersistence) and [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html) should give you further information.

Imagine you would have a mapping which would allow that it would totally sufficient to write an HQL query like e.g. `SELECT c FROM CustomerEntity AS c` which would return a single Entity. Via its accessors you could navigate through your graph.

It's also possible to write Joins in HQL, in this case you only have to tell which Entities should be joined like `SELECT c FROM CustomerEntity AS c JOIN c.request AS r ...` and you can omit the `ON` clause in the regular cases. Hibernate knows how the Entities are connected because of the mapping.

Of course your mappings should be well-considered regarding fetching the proper amount of data (eager vs. lazy) & (unidirectional vs. bidirectional). In some cases it will even be better to write queries tailored to your use case than navigating via Java methods to avoid performance penalties, but that is something you have to decide depending on data structure and data size.

Last but not least, you can also use [native SQL queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/query_native.html) if you need that, but then you have to take care on your own about mapping it to Java objects.